# Finding pattern in large binary file using C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, file, search, design-patterns

I have a ~700 MB binary file (non-text data); what I would like to do is search for a specific pattern of bytes that occurs in random locations throughout the file.  e.g. `0x? 0x? 0x55 0x? 0x? 0x55 0x? 0x? 0x55 0x? 0x? 0x55` and so on for 50 or so bytes in sequence.  The pattern I'd be searching for would be a sequence two random bytes with 0x55 occurring every two bytes.

That is, search for tables stored in the file with 0x55 being the delimiter, and then save the data contained in the tables or otherwise manipulate it.

Would the best option be simply going through every individual byte one at a time, and then looking ahead two bytes to see if the value is 0x55, and if it is, then looking ahead again and again to confirm that a table exists in that location?

Load the whole thing? fseek?  Buffer chunks, searching those one byte at a time?

What would be the best way of looking through this large file, and finding the pattern, using C or C++?

Comment: Are the random bytes different or all repetitions of a specific byte? Can this random byte be 0x55? is this a one shot or you have to search several 700Mb files for the same pattern?

Comment: How many 0x55 do you expect to see?

Comment: The two bytes in between 0x55 can be anything, including 0x55.  There are a few dozen tables, so 0x55 will be repeated many times throughout the file.

Comment: @Kyle: What happens if there are overlapping matches? Which one do you pick?

Comment: At least to me, the important point is: do you know anything about the alignment of the 0x55 bytes you care about? If they're all going to be at even (or all at odd) positions, that makes the search substantially easier and faster.

Comment: @Moron: The basic goal is to identify each table, and copy the table out to a text file, or other kind of file.  So, once the program finds a match for the pattern, it would copy the entire table (starting with the two bytes before the first 0x55 and ending with the final 0x55 in the table).  Since there are always two bytes between the delimiters, you know you have found a table if the value three bytes away is also 0x55, and the value three bytes away from that is also 0x55.  Hope that clears things up.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin:  Sadly, since the data between the tables is effectively random, I have no way of predicting the location of each table (i.e. the position of the 0x55 bytes).

Comment: @Kyle Lowry: Okay. Do we at least know the length/size of the tables or at least the minimum size?

Comment: @Jerry Coffin:  As far as I know (I don't have the file with me atm), not all the tables are the same size.  However, I don't recall ever seeing one that is smaller than 50 bytes or so.  In other words, I don't know what the minimum size is necessarily, but I can at least say that there will be no table with less than 10-20 entries (i.e. 10-20 pairs of bytes delimited with 0x55).

Comment: @Kyle Lowry: In that case, I'd use something like a variant of Boyer-Moore-Horspool. Start at the 20th and 21st byte. If neither of them is 0x55 move forward another 20 bytes, and so on.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin:  That is interesting.  I'll try it out sometime and see if I can get it working for me.  Thanks.  Though, I am still open to alternatives - I wouldn't mind having several different potentially workable solutions to try out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ultimately worked for me was a hybrid between the Boyer-Moore-Horspool algorithm (suggested by Jerry Coffin) and my own algorithm based on the structure of the tables and the data being stored.

Basically, the BMH algorithm caught most of the things I was looking for.  The obvious stuff.

But some tables did turn out to have odd formatting, and I had to implement a semi-intelligent search that would look at the data following each `0x55`, and figure out whether or not it was it was likely to be *good* data, or just random junk.

Oddly enough, I ended up implementing it in PHP rather than C++, and dumping the results right into a MySQL database for querying.  The search process only took around 5 minutes or less, and the results were largely good.  I did end up with a lot of junk data, but it caught everything that I needed it to, and (as far as I'm aware) did not leave any good data behind.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a great job for a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) matcher or a [deterministic finite automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite-state_machine).  These are high-power tools designed to do just what you're asking, and if you have them at your disposal you shouldn't have much trouble doing this sort of search.  In C++, consider looking into the [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) libraries, which should have all the functionality you need to knock this problem down.

Comment: Isn't a DFA kind of overkill for a one byte search string? The search is trivial to implement in a linear fashion without DFAs or regex engines.

Comment: @Billy ONeal- Perhaps I'm misreading the above question, but this doesn't look like it's just looking for one byte (it's looking for a particular pattern of bytes).  Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Moron: If those are show-stopping issues, you need to review whether C++ is the right language to use.

Comment: @BillyONeal: No, the search is trivial to implement in an O(n*m) fashion.  Or, in other words, the non-regex, non-DFA, naive solution will take about 50 times longer, since the search string is about 50 bytes long.

Comment: @Moron: Boost's license is *very* liberal; in a nutshell: you can redistribute binaries without any acknowledgement, source distribution requires acknowledgement.  It's not the only regex library, too.  It sounds like you don't understand anything about regex: they can be tested, don't have to be complicated (though they are a DSL), can handle 0x55 between the 0x55 delimiters, and have well-defined rules for overlapping matches.

Comment: @Moron: It is very clear that a regex will work easily. Second, why are you worrying about performance before there's even a plan to get it *working?*  However, I already gave the algorithmic complexity for the naive search (O(n*m)).  Since you can construct a DFA that searches in O(n), I have reason to believe that a regex could be about *50 times* faster.

Comment: @Moron: Why would you want to use regex to do something completely unrelated, like writing out the matched tables to a file or otherwise handling that data?  Why do you think the effort required to test and setup (and whatever else you expect me to include in that "etc" as you did above) will be significantly less if you re-invent a wheel?  You should really look into Boost; it sounds like you've been missing out on a great tool for superfluous reasons.

Comment: @Moron: Sometimes you actually have a nail and you should use a hammer.  Regex is expressly designed for pattern matching in strings.  You need *something* to find the pattern, the only question is what external library (regex or otherwise) you'll use, or how you will write it yourself instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Load the whole thing? fseek? Buffer chunks, searching those one byte at a time?

If you can load the whole thing into memory, you should probably use the memory mapping features provided by your platform. This way, the operating system can decide if it should keep large portions of the file in physical memory (i.e. the system has lots of free RAM at the moment), or if it should work only in smaller chunks.

Of course, this only works if you can fit the file into working set.